# application intent is not working, app is crashing

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-intent

The Intent is working for some activity's, for some specific activity intent is crashing I have changed and tried it in different ways but for some activity intent is not working, app is getting built but after running on the phone it does not show any error during the debugging time ? I tried it in different way but it still crashes can anyone help me solve it?

MainActivity java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button conee = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
        conee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        Button cupp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.b2);
        cupp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent ko = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main3Activity.class);
                startActivity(ko);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Main3Activity java

```
package cheercreams.design;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;


public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    }
}
```

MainActivity Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="cheercreams.design.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_x="25dp"
        android:layout_y="17dp"
        android:text="Cone"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="cup"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:text="Butterfly box"
        android:textSize="14dp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
        android:text="family pack"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b2"
        android:text="kulfi"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/b6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b3"
        android:text="stick"
        android:textSize="14dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b4"
        android:text="sundae"
        android:textSize="14dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b8"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b4"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b5"
        android:text="special pack"
        android:textSize="14dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/b9"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b5"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b6"
        android:text="cassette"
        android:textSize="14dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main3Activity Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="cheercreams.design.Main3Activity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/heading"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/i1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bs"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/i2"/>

    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:id="@+id/r1"
        android:rating="4.5"
        android:contextClickable="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/i1"
        />



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Type :"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/t4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Price:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/t5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/t6"
        android:text="@string/Rs"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/t5"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:text="500ml"
        android:layout_below="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/t4"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:text="1000ml"
        android:layout_below="@+id/r1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>



    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/i2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t1"
        android:background="@drawable/bs"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        />
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:id="@+id/i3"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/i2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bs"

        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/t5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="Add to Cart"
        android:background="@color/colorOrange"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cheercreams.design">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"   />
        <activity android:name=".Main3Activity"  />
        <activity android:name=".Main4Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main5Activity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Hi, we will appreciate the crash log..

Comment: Add the crash log.

Comment: Crash log is `LogCat`.

Comment: where is Main2Activity.class?

Answer (score 1):

You defined Main2Activity in manifest file but you **don't initiate Main2Activity class in package**.
So, You able to go only from MainActivity to Main3Activity but not to Main2Activity.